# how to transform kafka logs stored on file system into csv

Tags: apache-kafka

I have some logs that were generated with kafka that are currently stored in a .log format looking like this, on my computer:

[image]

I would like to convert those files into csv records, with message and times.
I know the question might probably seem too vague or unclear, sorry, but i'm really looking for a starting point to achieve this;

**note**: this is linked to the isoblue project and datasets [here](https://www.isoblue.org/docs/data/data/)

Answer (score 1):

Those files are encrypted.
Isn't easier if you to just write a consumer for those topics and write a CSV file?

Comment: They're not encrypted... They are just stored in a binary format.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the DumpLogSegments command. However, this will not output CSV, so you'd have to parse *something*

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-DumpLogSegment

> **Dump Log Segment**
>
> This can print the messages directly from the log files or just verify
>   the indexes correct for the logs
>
> ```
> bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments
> ```
>
> required argument "[files]"
>
> ```
> Option Description
> ------ -----------
> --deep-iteration if set, uses deep instead of shallow iteration
> --files <file1, file2, ...> REQUIRED: The comma separated list of data and index log files to be dumped
> --max-message-size <Integer: size> Size of largest message. (default: 5242880)
> --print-data-log if set, printing the messages content when dumping data logs
> --verify-index-only if set, just verify the index log without printing its content
> ```