# Kafka Consumer does not return records in active segment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently working with Kafka, more specifically with the ability to use the log compaction feature, as stated here : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction.

I'm using the kafka-clients java library :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, I create a topic in compaction mode, using this property :

```
"cleanup.policy"="compact"
"delete.retention.ms"="100"
"segment.ms"="100"
"min.cleanable.dirty.ratio"="0.01"
```

For test purpose, the broker has the property log.retention.check.interval.ms set to 1 second, in order to compact data every second.

Then, I producer 3 distinct batch of messages, in that specific order :

```
#1
"k1":"V1"
"k3":"V1"
"k2":"V1"
"k1":"V2"
#2 
"k2":"V2"
"k1":"V3"
"k1":"V4"
#3
"k4":"V1"
```

I wait between each batch of messages at least 3 seconds (waiting for log cleaner). When I use the console consumer, I have this result :

```
"k3":"V1"
"k2":"V2"
"k1":"V4"
"k4":"V1"
```

This is exactly what I expected. But, when I use the `KafkaConsumer` from the Java Library, I have this result :

```
"k3":"V1"
"k2":"V2"
"k1":"V4"
```

k4 is missing. What I understand is that k4 has been push in a specific segment called the head, and only the tail has been compacted. The way Kafka works with his tail and head has been very well explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61457387/3442635). It appears that in my case, the consumer never fully read the kafka topic : it exclude any data that is still in the "dirty" section (the head). So my question is simple : why the `KafkaConsumer` exclude the data in the head segment ? Am I missing a specific configuration in the properties of my consumer ?

The Java Snippet just in case :

```java
@SneakyThrows
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getConsumerProperties());) {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC_NAME));

        final ConsumerRecords<String, String> poll = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord : poll) {
            log.info("Key : {} with value : {}", consumerRecord.key(), consumerRecord.value());
        }
    }

}

private static Properties getConsumerProperties() {
    Properties result = new Properties();
    result.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    return result;
}
```

Here is the producer code :

```java
log.info("#####PRODUCING FIRST BATCH OF MESSAGES#####");
try (KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(getProducerProperties())) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k1", "V1"));
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k3", "V1"));
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k2", "V1"));
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k1", "V2"));
    producer.flush();
}

Thread.sleep(6000);
log.info("#####PRODUCING SECOND BATCH OF MESSAGES#####");

try (KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(getProducerProperties())) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k2", "V2"));
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k1", "V3"));
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k1", "V4"));
    producer.flush();
}

Thread.sleep(6000);
log.info("#####PRODUCING LAST MESSAGE#####");

try (KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(getProducerProperties())) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Constants.TOPIC_NAME, "k4", "V1"));
    producer.flush();
}
```

Edit 1 :
@OneCricketeer advised me to dump the log segment to be sure that k4 is actually in the topic.

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files 00000000000000000000.log,00000000000000000007.log

Dumping 00000000000000000000.log
Log starting offset: 0
baseOffset: 0 lastOffset: 3 count: 1 baseSequence: 0 lastSequence: 3 producerId: 0 producerEpoch: 0 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: false isControl: false deleteHorizonMs: OptionalLong.empty position: 0 CreateTime: 1679472971181 size: 72 magic: 2 compresscodec: none crc: 4285334185 isvalid: true
baseOffset: 4 lastOffset: 6 count: 2 baseSequence: 0 lastSequence: 2 producerId: 1 producerEpoch: 0 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: false isControl: false deleteHorizonMs: OptionalLong.empty position: 72 CreateTime: 1679472977314 size: 83 magic: 2 compresscodec: none crc: 840210644 isvalid: true
Dumping 00000000000000000007.log
Log starting offset: 7
baseOffset: 7 lastOffset: 7 count: 1 baseSequence: 0 lastSequence: 0 producerId: 2 producerEpoch: 0 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: false isControl: false deleteHorizonMs: OptionalLong.empty position: 0 CreateTime: 1679472983359 size: 72 magic: 2 compresscodec: none crc: 1528509131 isvalid: true
```

We can see here that I have two log files : 00, containing all my compacted data, 07 containing only the offset 7, which is the "k4" key.

I'm assuming that 07.log is the head segment and 00.log the tail.

Comment: It doesn't exclude the head. How do you know that k4 is actually in the topic? Did you dump the segment (not using Console consumer)? Please show your producer code

Comment: Also, it's not recommended to create 10 segments per second. That'll likely cause high IO thrashing and wear out your disks

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer for your answer. I edited my post with the producer code. I wait 6 seconds between each producer to make sure that the log cleaner has been executed. When I say that k4 is actually in the topic, I can actually retrieve it by using the kafka-console-consumer.sh. I agree that 10 segments per second is a bad setting, but I was just trying to understand the log compaction and the segment logic in Kafka. I do not intend to use that setting outside my test.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "dump the segment" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60175014/2308683

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer, I just edited my question with the dump segments. I think it confirms that k4 is actually in the topic.